# Why would my Toyota Corolla die soon after starting it?

Tags: toyota, battery, starting, alternator

I have a 1996 Toyota Corolla DX with about 200k miles on it.  It runs good for the most part, but recently had a problem where it would not start.  Napa tested my alternator, which failed, so I installed a new one.  Now the car starts but won't remain running. The battery is also new. What could be the cause?  Edit
today I've noticed white smoke coming from exhaust as t you car starts to overheat... Not when the engine is cool though, only as the car overheats. The white smoke combined with the over heat along with decreases in my fuel effeciency and acceleration makes me wonder if it's the head gasket

Answer (score 4):

Common things that can shut a car down after starting:

- bad or disconnected idle air control valve (hold the accelerator down after starting, see if it keeps the engine alive)
- bad or disconnected mass airflow sensor
- bad ignition switch
- blocked fuel filter (test your fuel pressure)
- weak fuel pump (test your fuel pressure with the engine off but the key at the 'on' position)

Comment: Hmm thanks...i could smell gasoline when idling while his is open... And yes, when the problem occurs ( usually after engine has warm ) i have to keep accelerator depressed to prevent it from stalling.  It also FEELS like a stall caused by no gas, although i have over a half tank

Comment: I'd definitely check your fuel filter (if you haven't changed it, it's probably about due), and your pump.

Comment: If you smell gasoline, there isn't enough air or spark to burn all of it. If keeping the accelerator pressed prevents stalling, it suggest the idle air control valve. Grab one from the junkyard and swap it just to confirm. It's an inexpensive park that is generally easy to replace.

Comment: After cleaning the idle air valve i started the corolla to find that it would now idle without help from the gas pedal... But the dam thing was shaking so hard!  I heard weird gasping noises coming from the air intake and when i turned the throttle i heard a distinct suction of air, almost like how a turbo would sound when switching gears except it was more of a vacuum.  It stalled immediately upon releasing the throttle.

Comment: Check for cracked hoses introducing air leaks between the airflow meter and the throttle body.

Comment: No cracked hoses but it's almost as if the filter is restricting the air flow due to the lurch when i turn the throttle... Like that first breath you take after choking.  I inspected the filter but it seems clean.  I have yet to check the fuel pressure though... But i feel like I'm close to a solution when tinking with the throttle.

Comment: Inspect the rest of the air intake, especially the tube in front of the airbox. Something may have gotten stuck in there. Keep playing with your throttle and try to find where the sound is coming from. Cleaning your throttle body may help as well. Make sure the mass airflow sensor is plugged in. Litterally, unplug it and replug it.

Comment: Thanks...i took off and cleaned intake, maf sensor, and throttle body and have the same problem.  But today I've noticed white smoke coming from exhaust as t you car starts to overheat... Not when the engine is cool though, only as the car overheats.  The white smoke combined with the over heat along with decreases in my fuel effeciency and acceleration makes me wonder if it's the head gasket.

Comment: Check your water/coolant lines as well as oil. If there is a damaged head gasket you'll have distinctly "coffee-and-cream" looking fluids. It's possible that you have more than one concurrent issue or that one issue caused another.

Comment: You may want to perform a compression leak-down test, that will tell you if it's the head gasket.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time to help me on this issue... Old thread but it needs closure.
Turned out to be the head gasket.  After noticing little puffs of white smoke coming from exhaust, i decided to run a quick check for a head gasket failure.  I removed the cap to my radiator, removed all spark plugs, disconnected fuel relay, and filled my radiator with water to the brim.  I then installed a spark plug in cylinder 1, left the rest open (to diagnose exact cylinder, I guess I wanted an idea of where my gasket was blown) and turned the ignition over a few times.  If bubbles or any gushing came from radiator cap, I could probably assume a gasket failure.  Cylinders 1 & 2 passed but 3 & 4 made water gush out of the radiator.  So now I'm waiting on the new gasket and I'm gonna attempt to replace it myself.